# Invoking Spring Stomp Websocket from Rest Api not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp-websocket

I have a requirement in which I have to send a message through spring stomp WebSocket from inside a rest API, after searching a lot on the internet I have found a solution, I tried that but it's not working. Although the same code working perfectly with @MessageMapping

```
    // @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat.sendMessage")
public void sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage// , Principal principal
) {

    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/private" + 1, chatMessage);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now,my bad, I forgot to change the code on client-side and still calling the stompClient.send() instead of calling the API